# Ruby hash kind of flatten

Tags: ruby, hash

Having this array of hashes, :

```
a = [{"red"=>"130"}, {"blue"=>"94"}, {"green"=>"57"}]
```

I want to get a full flatten hash like this:

```
{"red"=>"130", "blue"=>"94", "green"=>"57"}
```

Comment: hint: `reduce` + `merge`

Comment: How did you get that array of hashes? Usually, this sort of structure is the result of a `map` that wasn't written right. Show us how the first array was created and we can help you avoid this second step. See "[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"

Comment: @the-tin-man Precious!!! You were right! I've really been able to simplify "a lot" my data parsing and crunching, starting from your assumption. The first array was a complex multidimentional and multi-type nested data structure I get in responce to query & mixin, tens of differents external APIs. Thanks again, some times chenge your assumptions is all that's needed :)

Comment: I'm glad that helped. A lot of questions we see are due to people starting with the wrong data structure. Eventually we learn that complex structures we generate are often the result of doing something wrong early in the pipeline. Our data shouldn't have unexpected things in them and if we see them that's a warning we need to back up and take a different run at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
a = [{"red"=>"130"}, {"blue"=>"94"}, {"green"=>"57"}]
a.inject(:merge)
# => {"red"=>"130", "blue"=>"94", "green"=>"57"}
```

**NOTE** This will return `nil` if the array is empty.

```
a = []
a.inject(:merge)  # <---
# => nil
a.inject({}, :merge)
# => {}
```

Comment: Watch out though, this will return `nil` if the array is empty

Comment: @Doydle, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 3):

```
[{"red"=>"130"}, {"blue"=>"94"}, {"green"=>"57"}].reduce(:merge)
# => {"red"=>"130", "blue"=>"94", "green"=>"57"}
```

#### Notes:

1. Will return `nil` for empty arrays
2. Both: [**Enumerable#reduce**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [**Enumerable#inject**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) will work

Comment: this works this [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way use [`each_with_object(obj)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
a = [{"red"=>"130"}, {"blue"=>"94"}, {"green"=>"57"}]
a.each_with_object({}) { |h, o| o[h.keys.first] = h.values.first }
{"red"=>"130", "blue"=>"94", "green"=>"57"}
```

If the array is empty it is return a empty hash `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[*a.map(&:to_a).flatten]
# => {"red"=>"130", "blue"=>"94", "green"=>"57"}
```

Returns empty Hash for empty Array

```
Hash[*[].map(&:to_a).flatten]
# => {}
```

Comment: this work without splat(`*`) too, just flatten with 1 level `Hash[a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1)]`

Comment: map + flatten can also be replaced by flat_map  `a.flat_map(&:to_a).to_h`